# Is there any better way to query to the database to check if there exists some data in the database in one of the tables between the two?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know if there is some better way of querying to the database to check if some data exists in some column in one of the tables out of two. I am now using two queries to check if the data exists but I strongly believe there is some way.
Example: I have two tables in MySQL - suppliers and users. I need to check if username exists in either suppliers table or in the users table, and if not, allow client (don't get confused, client here means the client performing actions in the browser) to use the username. Assume I have two columns in both the tables:

Suppliers table: `supplier_id, supplier_username`

Users table:     `user_id, user_username`

I am currently querying two times to the database to check if username is available for use or not.

```
SELECT supplier_id FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_username = ?
```

Once I get the data, and if there are 0 rows, then do the same for users table and again if I get 0 rows, then username is available.

Username must be unique.

I need if there's better way (maybe a single query) to get whether the username is available to use or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One better way would be having a single table for all usernames...

Comment: Something like?: `SELECT 1 FROM suppliers LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_username = suppliers.supplier_username WHERE suppliers.supplier_username = ?` (that's why you wouldn't generally use things like `user_username` for the field name, `username` is enough).

Comment: Overall, this is a bad practice. You should have the user table as the source of truth for all your usernames. Then the username column in your supplier table should be foreign key'd to your user table so you maintain referential integrity. If it exists in the supplier table, it MUST exist in the user table and if it doesn't exist in the user table, you don't have that username yet.

Comment: I don't think it's bad practice... While signing up, it's anyways the same thing, insert username into the usernames table and put the username_id into the suppliers/users table. Anyway, thanks all for your help.

Comment: @CoderAmogh It is bad practice. You are checking multiple tables to determine if a user exists. That means you don't have a specific table which is the source of truth, which means you have data duplicated in a way that is not referential. If you are checking both tables to determine if something is available, that means there is a possibility that a user can be in the suppliers table, but not in the users table, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do an inner join. If 0 returns, it will tell you the record does not exist in both tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM suppliers s
INNER JOIN users u
ON s.supplier_username = u.user_username
WHERE u.user_username = @username
```

Comment: Technically you don't even need the `COUNT(*)` you can just do `SELECT 1` as you're only really interested in a yes/no type response.

Comment: @CD001 You can do that as well.

Comment: @CD001 If the OP has multiple suppliers in the suppliers table with the same username, that would result in more than a single row if you use SELECT 1. Either way, OP is asking for trouble with this setup.

Comment: Does it really matter if it results in more than one row? All you care about is whether `->rowCount() > 0` - but if usernames are to be unique for both users and suppliers then yes, a separate username table makes most sense... but **as I understand the question** it doesn't specify that `supplies.supplier_username` **must** be unique - merely that the "client" (I'm taking that to mean user) username must be unique and not the same as any supplier name.

Comment: @CD001 Why are you asking me? I'm not OP.

Comment: I was merely saying that even if `SELECT 1` results in multiple rows it shouldn't really matter. The rest of it was a long-winded way of basically saying "Yup, I agree with you otherwise" ;)

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry, I forgot to mention, usernames must be unique.

Comment: We should point out that if the username exists in the `users` table but not the `suppliers` table, then this will return a count of 0. That is, the username value must appear in BOTH the `users` AND the `suppliers` table to return a count greater than zero. This may meet the OP requirement, but my reading of the specification was that we should detect the username in either table.

Comment: @spencer7593 Meh. OP is going to have a rough time anyway since it sounds like neither table references the other. So a username could be in one, but not the other and there are no FKs.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation with table joins is that data from one table is always conditional on data from the other table.  In order to reference each table as it's own data set, you can use UNION to combine the lists.

```
SELECT supplier_id as id, supplier_username as name FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_username = '?'
UNION 
SELECT user_id, user_username FROM users WHERE user_username = '?'
```

Or you can take it a step further by using the Select union statement as the From clause, allowing sort order, partial search criteria, etc.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name 
from (SELECT s.supplier_id as id, s.supplier_username as name FROM suppliers as s
UNION 
SELECT u.user_id as id, u.user_username as name FROM users as u) as c
WHERE c.name like '%?%'
Order by c.name
```

Comment: On the second example, that inline view is going to get materialized into a derived table, and that is going to be expensive for large sets.  (MySQL doesn't push the predicate from the outer query down into the view.)  The `UNION` set operator is to require MySQL to perform a "Using filesort" operation to identify and remove duplicate rows. The `UNION ALL` set operator doesn't have that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

There's several possible query patterns.

A `UNION ALL` set operator can combine the results from two SELECTs, each SELECT has to return the same number of columns and columns of the same datatypes. We frequently include an additional discriminator column that tells us which SELECT returned which row.

For example:

```
( SELECT 's' AS src
       , s.supplier_id  AS id
    FROM suppliers s
   WHERE s.supplier_username = ?
)
UNION ALL 
( SELECT 'u' AS src
       , u.user_id
    FROM users u
   WHERE u.user_username = ?
)
```

Another alternative, if we don't need to retrieve the `id` value, and just want to get a count of the number of rows with a matching `supplier_username` / `user_username` , the n we could do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.supplier_id) + COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) AS cnt
  FROM ( SELECT 1 AS n ) i
  LEFT
  JOIN suppliers s
    ON s.supplier_username = ?
  LEFT
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user_username = ?
```